# How do JS-object-property descriptors being themselves objects NOT lead to an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In JavaScript, if

- i) every object property has a descriptor, and
- ii) every descriptor is an object, and
- iii) every descriptor has at least one property (which has a descriptor, which is an object, etc., etc.)

... then how is it that defining an object in JS with a single property does NOT require an infinite chain of objects and properties? Where/how does the buck stop? Which of these premises is deficient?

(Note: premises i-iii are based on my reading of the [Object.defineProperty() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: I'm no expert on this at all, but I think just because every object property *has* a descriptor (that is, a descriptor could be written down that describes it), it doesn't mean that every property *is* a descriptor (and therefore an object itself, leading to infinite regress). Whatever the underlying implementation is will likely not actually use JS objects, but some structure in I guess C or C++.

Comment: I’d say the flaw is with (ii). Every descriptor is not a JavaScript object; you can just *get* every descriptor in the form of a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, the desciptors have reference pointers for each objects.

The entity of each objects and its descriptors are in memory space one by one. (Just one for each.)

If you set a descriptor of another object for the property, that is the descriptor's pointer, not an entity of the descriptor itself.
So infinite loop will not occur.

About JavaScript objects:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects